# How to change some java variables before deploying on a remote server?

Tags: maven, tomcat, jenkins, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I am currently building a java web application (with netbeans).
I use Jenkins to create a release version with the following pipeline (for Jenkins):

Build -> Test -> Deploy (to a remote test webserver)

Build and Test are OK but I have a question about the deploy job.
The deploy job is currently taking my previously generated .war file and simply transfer it to a remote web server (with the "Deploy to container" plugin).
But I would like to change the database parameters of my web application first ! (in order to use another remote test database).
I would be glad to modify the java file with shell command but I can't because my .war is only composed of the compiled .class java.

So how could I change some of my web application java code (for database credentials) from the .war file before deploying it to the remote web server ?

Comment: You should not put configuration data in code in the first place. Move the credentials to a property file, and read that file to obtain the credentials. Then the property file can be edited after deployment in different environments. This also avoids other security concerns such as credentials being visible in your SCS, and developers needing to know Production passwords. But that is only an initial step to resolve your immediate problem, and there are multiple solutions. See [How should an application store its credentials](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/20294) for more ideas.

Comment: Although you have framed your question very specifically in terms of Java, since the larger issue is how to deploy application code to different environments, I'm not sure that it really belongs on SO. You might try the [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) site instead. Your question is also inviting opinions, which could make it off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple environments which have different databases, then the best way to handle this would be application with command line parameters. You can modify your java application to read the command line parameters and use these parameters in application.

For example `--dburl = <database url> --dbusername= <db username>`

And the another way will be take these paramters from environment variable. And define these variables in the system where you are deploying the applications.